# Angular 10 | Different ID types | How to add css style with css file

Tags: html, css, angular

I do not really understand the difference between these three ways to declare an ID in html:

1. `[id] = "'example'"`
2. `id = "example"`
3. `#example`

The first two seem to be identical, is this correct?
These I can style in my `example.component.css` file.

The third one is special. I understand I can use it everywhere in the current html view, but I cannot apply CSS styles with `example.component.css`, is this correct?

Which one shall I use in angular? A combination of 1/2 and 3?

I also noticed if I use the same ID in different components, I will have duplicate ID's, which is really bad, so eventhough I use angular and different components I must be very careful how I name ID's, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2 is the default html syntax for an id

Version 1 is the angular way, if the id is a variable, e.g. [id]="myId"

Version 3 is the angular way to export/reference a html element to angular. This is not an id.

The id is a HTML Element (not angular), so you have to look that the id in html after building is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the first two have an identical end result. The second one is a string while the first one is a javascript expression and is evaluated by angular. This means you can use things like component properties such as `[id]="'example-' . foo"` which outputs `id="example-2"` if you had a property `foo = 2;` in your component.

The third one actually doesn't have anything to do with the ID attribute in HTML, but I understand why it may seem like it. It's actually a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-reference-variables-var) and it allows you to access this element from anywhere else in your template, or even from your component code.

You're right, the html specification requires an ID to be unique, browsers are forgiving so they may permit you to use duplicate IDs but it should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `id="unique_id"` if you don't want to change it dynamically. If you want to change your HTML element `id` dynamically through `Component.ts` then you should use [id]="your_variable" & `#example` serves for different purpose described below.

- `id` with `[]` brackets is angular directive to set HTML id attribute value through a variable or expression
- `id` is a HTML attribute which sets a unique id on an element
- `#example` if you are writing like this in `Component.html` you are basically creating a template reference variable which is a reference to a DOM element within a template. You can then access this using Angular `@ViewChild` decorator. It can also refer to a directive (which contains a component), an element, TemplateRef, or a web component.

[Angular Template Reference Variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)

Answer (score 0):

`[id] = "'example'"` => This one set assign example as id and it is same as id = "example".

Suppose if we want to assign a variable value then use [id] = "example".For this in ts file you have to declare the example variable

```
Public example ="your-class-name";
```

So id value will be your-class-name

#example => These are templare refference variable.

A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template.

For example,

```
<input #phone placeholder="phone number" />

<!-- lots of other elements -->

<!-- phone refers to the input element; pass its `value` to an event handler -->
<button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>
```